# WPF Databinding: Updating an Item in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am trying to reflect an ObservableCollection's changes in a WPF DataGrid. Additions and removals to the list work great, but I'm stuck on edits.

I initialize the ObservableCollection in my constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.itemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = this.itemList;
    DataGrid.DataContext = this.itemList;
}
```

I have a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Additions to the ObservableCollection work great:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() => this.itemList.Add(new Item { FirstName = firstName })));
```

**TL;DR**

My question is, how do I update an item in the list while allowing databinding to update my GridView?

I have not been able to achieve it, except by shamefully removing and re-adding the item:

```
item.FirstName = newFirstName;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.itemList.Remove(item)));
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.itemList.Add(item)));
```

**UPDATE**

Per comment request, here is more code on how I'm doing the update:

```
foreach (var thisItem in this.itemList)
{
    var item = thisItem;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName))
    {
        continue;
    }

    var newFirstName = "Joe";

    item.FirstName = newFirstName; // If I stop here, the collection updates but not the UI. Updating the UI happens with the below calls.

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.itemList.Remove(item)));
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.itemList.Add(item)));

    break;
}
```

Comment: Show how the update is being done

Comment: I appended a code sample with more on the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Item` object is not complete. There's actually no notification of change on the `FirstName` property. The `FirstName` property should be:

```
private string _firstName;
public string FirstName 
{ 
    get{return _firstName;}
    set
    {
        if (_firstName == value) return;
        _firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Touché on the property naming. To appease my own confusion, I just updated my sample and renamed the property `FirstName`.

Comment: Not touché, just wrote this in the web editor so no validation. Tried to validate by eye and all I saw is _valueValue_valuevalueValue. Not a biggie, just funny (thus the smiley). With VS/R# validation it's not an issue at all.

Comment: Worked great! I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to match the changes I made to my question. `Value` was confusing me!

Comment: Great! I've approved the edit and removed the comment about naming (<-clarification for future readers of comments)